# Classcast exception when trying to use Vault to fetch Contentful CMS data on Android

Tags: android, contentful

I am trying to fetch entries from Contentful CMS into my Android app. For this i am using Vault. I have defined the following Model in my application -

```
@ContentType("transportInfo")
public class TransportModel extends Resource {
    @Field String title;
    @Field List<Asset> gallery;
    @Field String description;
    @Field List<Asset> mapImage;
    @Field String phoneNumber;
    @Field String type;
    @Field Asset dayListImage;
    @Field Asset nightListImage;
    @Field String listSubtitle;
    @Field Integer sortIndex;
    @Field String dayHighlightColor;
    @Field String nightHighlightColor;
    @Field Integer numberOfZones;
    @Field Integer numberOfStations;
    @Field Integer totalKilometers;
    @Field String webSite;
}
```

Following is my sync code-

```
CDAClient cdaClient = CDAClient.builder()
        .setSpace(getResources().getString(R.string.space_id))
        .setToken(getResources().getString(R.string.cms_token))
        .build();

mClient.appCDAClient = cdaClient;
SyncConfig config = SyncConfig.builder()
        .setClient(cdaClient)
        .build();

//sync
Vault.with(getActivity(), TransportSpace.class).requestSync(config, new SyncCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(SyncResult result) {
        result.error();
        Vault vault = Vault.with(getActivity(), TransportSpace.class);
        List<TransportModel> response =  vault.fetch(TransportModel.class)
                .all();
        response.size();
    }

});
```

The result of the above sync request gives me the following error -

**java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.List**

I am assuming this is due to the gallery field. But can someone please help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

my name is Mario Bodemann, and I am a developer at Contentful.

Please make sure to use the most current version of the Contentful libraries: contentful.java: 7.0.2, Vault: 2.0.0

This should fix the problem, if not, let us take a look at it together...

Greetings, Mario